# AngularJs $scope is undefined in ionic project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building a project with ionic.

Here is my simple controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

app.controller("loginController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.userName = ""
    $scope.password = ""

    $scope.login = function(){
        //some login things here
    };
}]);
```

My HTML

```
 <ion-content ng-controller="loginController">
            <form class="list" ng-submit="login()">
              <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Username</span>
              <input type="text" ng-bind="userName">
              </label>
              <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Password</span>
              <input type="password" ng-bind="password">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-block button-positive">
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
</ion-content>
```

When i click to login button, `Login` function is runing but i can't access to `userName` and `password` variables because meanwhile `$scope` is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `ngModel` directives on input fields instead of `ngBind`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userName">
```

Complete HTML code then will become:

```
<form class="list" ng-submit="login()">
    <label class="item item-input"> 
        <span class="input-label">Username</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="userName">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input"> 
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" ng-model="password">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-block button-positive">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That works. I'll mark this as answer when it's possible. Thanks.